# it is possible to change a result with an if or cause function

Tags: sql

I would like to multiply the result of the "Employees" column by a factor later. It should look like this.

With result 3 the factor 1.4 should appear, with result 4 the factor 1.6 and with 5 the factor 1.8

My Query

```
 SELECT  b.masch_nr, SUM(b.ruest_zeit) as Rüstzeit, SUM(b.bearb_zeit) as Bearbzeit, SUM(s.bmk_07) as 
 Istrüstzeit,SUM(s.bmk_11) as Istbearbzeit,SUM(b.user_n_15) as Sollanzahl,


       (select SUM(p.user_n_07) FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[ade_protokoll] p
       JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
       ON p.auftrag_nr = b.auftrag_nr
   WHERE b.masch_nr='QTA5VERP'
   AND p.anmeld_dat = DATEADD(day, -0, convert(date, GETDATE()))
       AND p.schichtnr = '1'
       AND p.satz_art = 'T') as Istanzahl,

  (select COUNT(DISTINCT p.person_nr1) FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[ade_protokoll] p
       WHERE p.masch_nr IN ('QTA5','QTA5VERP')
       AND p.anmeld_dat = DATEADD(day, -0, convert(date, GETDATE()))
       AND p.schichtnr = '1' ) as Employees

 FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
 JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrag_status] s
 ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
 WHERE b.masch_nr = 'QTA5'
 AND s.prot_dat = DATEADD(day, -0, convert(date, GETDATE()))
 AND s.anmeldzeit BETWEEN '21600' AND '50400'
 AND s.a_status IN ('E','L')
 GROUP BY b.masch_nr
```

Here my result and wish in yellow

[image]

or directly in the employees column

[image]

Is that possible with an if or cause function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Is there a formula by which the factor is derived from the number of employees, or are the only possible values the ones that you have listed?  For a small number of values, such as those you have listed, a hard-coded `case` expression would do it.

Comment: Ok i have found a solution with case function. Thank you very much